# How do I erase the label and just have a placeholder in the input box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been poking around with this form for a while but I am unable to erase the label that goes on the left hand corner above the input box and just have the placeholder text inside an input box. With the code below, the input box gets filled with the placeholder value but the label becomes the argument of the input method on the variable f.

I would like to just have to value of the placeholder inside the input box with no labels.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "e-mail", required: false, autofocus: true %>
            <%= f.input :password, placeholder: "password",required: false, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length}文字以上で！" if @minimum_password_length) %>
            <%= f.input :password_confirmation, placeholder: "password", required: false %>  
        </div>
```

Comment: It's better to [hide the label with css](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) and add a placeholder for accessibility. Or you can position the label on the input.

Comment: Just add `label: false` and try: `<%= f.input :email, placeholder: "e-mail", required: false, autofocus: true, label: false %>`

Comment: @Deep Thank you!It worked!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `label: false` like this:

```
<%= f.input :email, placeholder: "e-mail", required: false, autofocus: true, label: false %>
```

This will remove the label.